# unable to perform multipart form upload using rest-assured

Tags: rest, upload, multipart, rest-assured

I am trying to upload file using multipart form upload using the following rest-assured method.

```
given().filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(captor)).when().multiPart("metadata", new File("S:\\testdata.prop")).multiPart("file",aFileStream).post("/uploadFile").then().statusCode(200);
```

This throws an error that

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule could not be
>   instantiated.

jackson library is added to classpath.the testdata.Prop file is a properties file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jackson-databind` to the classpath. If you're using Maven you can add it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also if you're using JodaTime you may need to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

REST Assured automatically tries to register all jackson modules in classpath.